# Lock Cells after Data Entry

Tags: excel, locking, before-save, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is edited by multiple users. To prevent tampering with previous data the cells are locked once data has been entered and the file saved. I have a few small bugs in the code though:

1. Even if the user has saved manually and then exits the application they are still prompted to save again.
2. The cells should be locked after a save when the application is running and not just when it is exited. Previously I had this code in the before_save event but the cells were being locked even if a save_as event was cancelled so I removed the code for now. **Fixed**

(Edit: I've just realised how obvious this error was. I even said it in this statement! Trying to lock cells after a save event using a before save event sub! )

**Code**

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            Cell.Locked = False
        Else
            Cell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next Cell
    .Protect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
End With
```

The workbook open, hide all sheets and show all sheets subs are used to force the end user into enabling macros. Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Const WelcomePage = "Macros"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim vFilename As Variant
    Dim bSaved As Boolean

'Turn off screen updating
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

'Record active worksheet
 Set wsActive = ActiveSheet

'Prompt for Save As
If SaveAsUI = True Then
    vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
    If CStr(vFilename) = "False" Then
        bSaved = False
    Else
        'Save the workbook using the supplied filename
        Call HideAllSheets
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs vFilename
        Application.RecentFiles.Add vFilename
        Call ShowAllSheets
        bSaved = True
    End If
Else
    'Save the workbook
    Call HideAllSheets
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Call ShowAllSheets
    bSaved = True
End If


'Restore file to where user was
wsActive.Activate
'Restore screen updates
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

'Set application states appropriately
If bSaved Then
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Cancel = True
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call ShowAllSheets
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

Private Sub HideAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = WelcomePage Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next ws
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = WelcomePage Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub

'Lock Cells upon exit save if data has been entered
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Cell As Range
With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Cell.Value = "" Then
            Cell.Locked = False
        Else
            Cell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next Cell
    .Protect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is asking for them to save before exiting even though they have already saved because of these lines:

```
'Save the workbook
Call HideAllSheets
ThisWorkbook.Save
Call ShowAllSheets
bSaved = True
```

You are changing the worksheet after saving it (by calling ShowAllSheets) so it does need to be saved again.  The same is true of the saveAs code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the second problem by using another IF. This ensures the cells are only locked if the data is saved:

```
'Lock Cells before save if data has been entered
    Dim rpcell As Range
With ActiveSheet
    If bSaved = True Then
    .Unprotect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rpcell.Value = "" Then
            rpcell.Locked = False
        Else
            rpcell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next rpcell
    .Protect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    Else
    MsgBox "The LogBook was not saved. You are free to edit the RP Log again", vbOKOnly, "LogBook Not Saved"
    End If
End With
```