# Cell Locking on Save if data has been entered

Tags: excel, locking, vba

This is a follow up from this question, [Lock Cells after Data Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396006/lock-cells-after-data-entry). I have progressed from asking that question but encountered more problems so felt I should ask a new question. The workbook is edited by multiple users. To prevent tampering with previous data the cells are locked once data has been entered and the file saved.

I have a couple of small bugs in the code:

1. If the user chooses to `SaveAs` then tries to save over an existing file the usual ' Do you want to replace this file?' dialog appears. If the user selects no there is a run time error. I have highlighted where the error is in the code below but I am unsure how to fix it.
2. If the user has entered data then tries to exit and save the file using the save dialog box that appears on close the file is saved but the data is not locked. I have been trying to call my main code to lock the cells upon an exit save but I keep encountering argument not optional errors.

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit
Const WelcomePage = "Macros"
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Written by Alistair Weir (alistair.weir@communitypharmacyscotland.org.uk, http://alistairweir.blogspot.co.uk/)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim vFilename As Variant
Dim bSaved As Boolean

'Turn off screen updating
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Record active worksheet
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet

'Prompt for Save As
If SaveAsUI = True Then
    MsgBox "Are you sure you want to save? Data entered cannot be edited once the file has been saved. Press cancel on the next screen to edit your data or continue if you are sure it is correct.", vbCritical, "Are you sure?"

    vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
    If CStr(vFilename) = "False" Then
        bSaved = False
    Else
        'Save the workbook using the supplied filename
        Call HideAllSheets
        '--> The vFilename Variant in the next line is the problem **
        '--> when trying to overwrite an existing file  **
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs vFilename
        Application.RecentFiles.Add vFilename
        Call ShowAllSheets
        bSaved = True
    End If
Else
    'Save the workbook, prompt if normal save selected not save As
    Call HideAllSheets
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save? Data entered cannot be edited after saving", vbYesNo, "Save?") = vbYes Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Call ShowAllSheets
        bSaved = True
        Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Call ShowAllSheets
End If

'Restore file to where user was
wsActive.Activate
'Restore screen updates
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

'Set application states appropriately
If bSaved Then
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Cancel = True
Else
    Cancel = True
End If

'Lock Cells before save if data has been entered
    Dim rpcell As Range
With ActiveSheet
    If bSaved = True Then
    .Unprotect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rpcell.Value = "" Then
            rpcell.Locked = False
        Else
            rpcell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next rpcell
    .Protect Password:="oVc0obr02WpXeZGy"
    Else
    MsgBox "The LogBook was not saved. You are free to edit the RP Log again", vbOKOnly, "LogBook Not Saved"
    End If
End With

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call ShowAllSheets
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

'Called to hide all the sheets but enable macros page
Private Sub HideAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = WelcomePage Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next ws
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Activate
End Sub

'Called to show the data sheets when macros are enabled
Private Sub ShowAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = WelcomePage Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws
    Worksheets(WelcomePage).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Thanks :)

**Edit**

For now I am solving problem 2 by bypassing excel's default 'do you want to save?' by doing this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to quit? Any unsaved changes will be lost.", vbYesNo, "Really quit?") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    Else
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

I am open to suggestions of a better way and still haven't solved the first problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to write your own confirmations in a save function, like so:

```
Private Function SaveSheet(Optional fileName) As Boolean

HideAllSheets

If fileName = "" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    SaveSheet = True
Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Dir(fileName) <> "" Then
        If MsgBox("Worksheet exists. Overwrite?", vbYesNo, "Exists") = vbNo Then Exit Function
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.saveAs fileName
    SaveSheet = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

ShowAllSheets

End Function
```

And change your original code to something like:

```
If SaveAsUI Then
    If MsgBox( _
        "Are you sure you want to save? Data entered cannot be edited once the file has been saved. " & _
        "Press cancel on the next screen to edit your data or continue if you are sure it is correct.", _
        vbYesNo, "Are you sure?" _
    ) = vbYes Then
        vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")

        If vFilename <> "" Then
            If SaveSheet(vFilename) Then bSaved = True
        End If
    End If
Else
    If MsgBox( _
        "Are you sure you want to save? Data entered cannot be edited after saving", _
        vbYesNo, "Save?" _
    ) = vbYes Then
        If SaveSheet("") Then bSaved = True
    End If
End If
```

I've not fully tested the above, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: If the user says yes to the first vb box then cancels in the save as dialog there is a run time error at `Dir(filename) <> ...` What does a Dir command do?

Comment: Dir(filename) returns the filename if the file exists. If they cancel the save as dialog box, you don't want to enter the SaveSheet function, so change the 'If vFilename <> "" Then' line so that it doesn't enter the condition.